# Confused on recreating/understanding decision value vs probability density graph

Tags: python, graph, binary, classification

I have this graph that I was told to recreate for my xgboost binary classifier but then I wasnt given any further guidance. It is a graph of logit(Decision Value) vs log(Probability Density). I see there are 4 colors, does that mean I should make 4 subsets, one for class 0 test, one for class 0 val, one for class 1 test and one for class 1 val? Also what is probability density and decision value in this context. I'm assuming you use get one of them with model.predict_proba but I'm not sure which. Also I dont even know what the other value is/ how to get it. Also what does the log/logit do in this context. I would appreciate any help/explanations greatly.

[The Graph In Question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtPVM.png)

I'm not sure where to go, I dont even know how to do this conceptually.